# How to generate IDs' in order according to the date in c#

Tags: c#, date, uniqueidentifier, auto-generate, inorder

How to generate ID's for users upon their registration. The kind of ID's that I want goes in this format: (ABCDEF2015xxx). For example, first user that registers in 2015 will have this id: ABCDEF2015001. The next user will have the id : ABCDEF2015002. And in the next year the first user will have the id: ABCDEF2016001.

Regards.

Comment: Is this going inside a database of some kind?

Comment: Yes it is. And it should be in order

Comment: What database?  You may be able to use composite keys...

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL database

Comment: Because it represents something in the community that I'm creating this for.

Comment: I hope this isn't the primary key.  It's considered poor practice to put any semantic meaning in a primary key (usually, the primary key should be a simple integer).

Comment: Why not just use integers? The only valid case I see for using special keys is when you use GUIDs to make it easier to merge databases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that by using trigger. I never used mysql. But googled and wrote some sample trigger. I might not work just like that, you may need to fix some issue. But you can follow the same idea.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES (NULL);
    $query = mysql_query(CONCAT('SELECT max(CAST(SUBSTRING(id,11) AS BIGINT)) as id FROM table1 where SUBSTRING(ID,7,4) =',CAST(YEAR() AS CHAR))); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    $lastId =  $row->id;
  }
  if($lastid IS NULL) THEN
  $newid = CONCAT('ABCDEF', CAST(YEAR() AS CHAR), '001')
  ELSE
  $newid = CONCAT('ABCDEF', CAST(YEAR() AS CHAR), CAST($lastId+1 AS CHAR))
  END IF;
  SET NEW.id = $newid;
END$$
```